# Unir dos filas con distintos valores en una sola en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla (`unidades`) que cuenta con 3 campos `TIPO UNIDAD`, `NOMBRE`, `CLAVE`.

| tipo unidad | nombre | clave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tractor | t1 | 100 |
| Caja | c1 | 100 |
| Tractor | t10 | 200 |
| Caja | c10 | 200 |
| Tractor | t100 | 500 |
| Caja | c100 | 500 |

Estoy tratando de agrupar por clave y mostrarlo en una sola fila el nombre del tractor así como el nombre de la caja.

Ejemplo:

```txt
tractor:t1   |  caja:c1    |  clave:100
________________________________________
tractor:t10  |  caja:c10   |  clave:200
________________________________________
tractor:t100 |  caja:c100  |  clave:500
________________________________________
```

Tengo este query que me saca el nombre de las unidades, solo que me muestra en filas diferentes.

```sql
SELECT tipounidad, 
(CASE WHEN tipounidad = 'tractor' THEN nombre ELSE '' END) AS tractor,
(CASE WHEN tipounidad = 'caja' THEN nombre ELSE '' END) AS caja 
FROM unidades 
GROUP BY clave, nombre;
```

Pero no tengo idea de cómo agrupar por clave y unir los nombres de las unidades en una sola fila.

Comment: Lo que intentas hacer la verdad no le veo mucho sentido. Si lo que deseas es ordenar los datos vas a tener que buscar otra manera luego de consultarlos. Lo que mas se acerca a lo que quieres es algo asi: SELECT CONCAT(tipo_unidad,':',nombre) AS tipo, CONCAT('clave:',clave) AS Clave FROM stack.unidades
ORDER BY tipo ASC;

Comment: Quita `nombre` del `GROUP BY` y antepon [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) al paréntesis de los `CASE`. O en lugar de CASE puedes hacer: `group_concat(if(tipounidad='Tractor',nombre,null)) tractor`.

Comment: ¿Realmente quieres repetir el nombre de la columna en cada valor? supongo que lo pusiste así para explicar el orígen del dato.

Comment: lo de poner el nombre de la columna solo era para la explicación, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías combinar `GROUP_CONCAT()` con tus `CASE WHEN` para obtener el resultado esperado. Para evitar los `ELSE`, se agrega un criterio `WHERE` que filtre solamente `Tractor` y `Caja`. Si los índices están bien puestos en la tabla, la consulta queda optimizada de este modo.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo:

```
CREATE TABLE unidades (
  tipounidad VARCHAR(12),
  nombre VARCHAR(8),
  clave INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO unidades (tipounidad, nombre, clave) VALUES
('Tractor', 't1', 100),
('Caja', 'c1', 100),
('Tractor', 't10', 200),
('Caja', 'c10', 200),
('Tractor', 't100', 500),
('Caja', 'c100', 500);
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE 
            WHEN tipounidad = 'tractor' 
            THEN CONCAT(tipounidad,' : ',nombre) END SEPARATOR ''
    ) AS tractor,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE 
            WHEN tipounidad = 'caja' 
            THEN CONCAT(tipounidad,' : ',nombre) END SEPARATOR '') 
    AS caja
FROM unidades
  WHERE tipounidad IN('Tractor','Caja')
GROUP BY clave;
```

| tractor | caja |
| --- | --- |
| Tractor : t1 | Caja : c1 |
| Tractor : t10 | Caja : c10 |
| Tractor : t100 | Caja : c100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T0cFXSgJ)

Ten en cuenta que `GROUP_CONCAT` podría ser bastante útil también en el caso de necesitar un resultado ligero, por ejemplo para trabajarlo por código posteriormente.

Imaginemos que quisieras una sola columna, con los tractores y las cajas y un separador, podrías hacer algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE unidades (
  tipounidad VARCHAR(12),
  nombre VARCHAR(8),
  clave INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO unidades (tipounidad, nombre, clave) VALUES
('Tractor', 't1', 100),
('Caja', 'c1', 100),
('Tractor', 't10', 200),
('Caja', 'c10', 200),
('Tractor', 't100', 500),
('Caja', 'c100', 500);
```

> ```
> Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(tipounidad,' : ',nombre) SEPARATOR '|'
    ) AS data
FROM unidades
  WHERE tipounidad IN('Tractor','Caja')
GROUP BY clave;
```

| data |
| --- |
| Tractor : t1|Caja : c1 |
| Tractor : t10|Caja : c10 |
| Tractor : t100|Caja : c100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-F55Itnj)

En `data` tienes por decirlo así tus dos columnas en una, mediante el separador `|`.

Otra ventaja de `GROUP_CONCAT` es que te permite ordenar los resultados.

Para cualquier otro detalle [revisa la documentación en el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 2):

Podes obtener el resultado así:

1. Primero hacemos un `SELECT` sobre la tabla `unidades` para buscar los tipo `Tractor`.
2. Luego hacemos un `JOIN` con la misma tabla pero para buscar los tipo `Caja` que tengan la misma clave.

#### Ejemplo:

```sql
SELECT
    CONCAT(T.tipounidad, ':', T.nombre) AS tractor,
    CONCAT(C.tipounidad, ':', C.nombre) AS caja,
    CONCAT('clave:', T.clave) AS clave
FROM unidades AS T
    INNER JOIN unidades AS C
        ON C.clave = T.clave
        AND C.tipounidad = 'Caja'
WHERE T.tipounidad = 'Tractor'
```

#### Resultado:

| tractor | caja | clave |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tractor:t1 | Caja:c1 | clave:100 |
| Tractor:t10 | Caja:c10 | clave:200 |
| Tractor:t100 | Caja:c100 | clave:500 |

---

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iownFom8StgNRBqeFp8fRz/0)</kbd>

Comment: Hola Marcos. El problema de esta consulta es que lee las filas de la tabla `x N`, donde `N` sería el nùmero de criterios, tractores y cajas por ahora, pero ¿y si fueran 20 criterios? . Ahora son 6 filas, lee `6 x 2 = 12`. Si son 5000 filas leerá 10,000, si fueran 5000 filas y 10 criterios, leerá 5000 x 10 ... y así exponencialmente. Lo puedes comprobar poniendo `EXPLAIN` delante del `SELECT`. Nada justifica aquí hacer un `JOIN` de la tabla consigo misma, cuando puedes usar `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY` por ejemplo para obtener el resultado esperado.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano. Si bien es cierto el planteo respecto a las de comparaciones, no estoy seguro en que _"nada justifica hacer un `JOIN`"_. Si vamos a especular sobre futuras necesidades, puede que el OP necesite obtener resultados SI Y SOLO SI existen registros relacionados y condicionados, punto que tu respuesta aún no solucionaria. PD: considero que tu respuesta es muy buena, no se me ocurrio verlo de esa forma.

Comment: Para el tipo de resultados que OP espera obtener aquí no se justifica hacer un JOIN de la tabla consigo misma que provoque una lectura de filas multiplicada por `N`, donde `N` sería el número de casos y/o criterios. Me refiero a eso, Marcos. En una consulta de este tipo vas a tener problemas tarde o temprano, de rendimiento y/o de mantenimiento cuando sea necesario agregar más casos por ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano. Me tome el tiempo para hacer la prueba. Entonces agregue 3 indices (_para optimizar la consultas_) y con exactamente 2.000 registros (_mil de cada uno_) puedo decir que **estas equivocado**. 1. El `EXPLAIN` de mi consulta no refleja lo planeado en tus comentarios. 2. El `BENCHMARK` de 1000 veces mi consulta más rápido. 3. Mi consulta se ejecuta más rápido. Obviamente esto es en mi entorno. Te las 2 pruebas, [mi consulta](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioBFhwWxN6tCmuN3caJtvE/2) y [tu consulta](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioBFhwWxN6tCmuN3caJtvE/3). Saludos!

Comment: Como el fiddle algunas veces no refleja lo que digo en el punto 3 dejo estas caputras, [mi consulta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VQM0.png) y [tu consulta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2DDp.png)